# Java - software/JAR auto actualizable

Tags: java

Yo sé que la idea del foro es antes que nada mostrar código de lo que estamos haciendo, pero realmente no sé por donde empezar, por eso lo posteo (y dejo a consideración de los administradores cerrar el post si lo creen conveniente). Necesito que mi software, en java puro, es un demonio que corre sin front-end, se auto-actualice bajo ciertas circunstancias (archivo en un server que lo indique o algo por el estilo). Realmente no se me ocurre como hacerlo (sino pondría el código de la idea como lo hago siempre).
Se me ocurre que el sistema debe mirar un directorio de la red interna, una url o algo y si determina que es necesario actualizarse, debe:

1- Bajar los archivos
2- Cerrarse 
3- Copiar los archivos para sobreescribirse
4- Arrancar nuevamente

Ahora bien...no veo como poder hacer los puntos 3 y 4...se me ocurre que tendria que ser una combinacion de 2 programas (javas) que trabajen "coordinadamente"...no le encuentro la forma.

NO PRETENDO el codigo...SI al menos una idea de como hacerlo o por donde guiarme. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si usas algun versionador puedes crea un repositorio y configurar una instancia de [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io). Mas info en la documentación de Jenkins: [Crear una app Java con Maven](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/),  y en [Jenkins y Java](https://jenkins.io/solutions/java/)

Comment: @Killbunny gracias por el comentario, pero no seria posible. Es una red wifi (cerrada) y a la cual no tendria acceso para instalar jenkins mas que nada porque es una red dentro de un predio rural. La red es limitadisima en cuanto a recursos...solo me dará un directorio para colgar ahi la actualizacion y los clientes (moviles) podran accederla cuando esten en la red

Comment: Podrias hacer que la carpeta donde tienes la aplicación sea accesible desde FTP y crear una [tarea programada](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Windows-7/1400211-Como-crear-una-tarea-programada-en-Windows-7.html) que cada cierto tiempo, o evento ejecute un batch que haga la sustitución del archivo. Algo así como esto: `timeout /T 5 DEL MiAppBackup.jar
timeout /T 1
REN MiApp.jar MiAppBackup.jar
timeout /T 1
REN MiAppNuevo.jar MiApp.jar
timeout /T 1
START "" "MiApp.jar"`

Comment: @Killbunny uso linux

Comment: Ese era un batch de ejemplo, en Linux tienes los [CRON](https://www.nerion.es/soporte/tutoriales/tareas-programadas-en-linux/) y para la sustitucion de archivos puedes cambiar los `REN` (renombrar) por `MV` ( [como renombrar archivos en linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-rename-files/) )